# How to disable request "spam" with ispCP Omega?

Tags: php, apache2, debian, lenny

Im running ispCP Omega on a Debian Lenny server .. (im the admin)

Im coding on server-side javascript and i need to refresh often
So i regulary get this message (because, the server think i request spam it)

Forbidden
You don't have permission to access [hidden yeah, hidden] on this server.
Additionally, a 404 Not Found error was encountered while trying to use an ErrorDocument to handle the request.

else if you dont know ispcp, do you know a apache2 mod that could cause this ?

How i can reduce the treshold of (temp ban) forbidden errors ? Or best : remove it ?

Thanks you "alot" much ;P

Comment: i have same issue, did you solve it?

Comment: yep, you juste have to "a2dismod evasive"

Answer (score 0, accepted):

i found the answer you need to "a2dismod evasive"